# Display different font sizes in the same line

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to display the name and age on the same line (without one appearing above the line) although they have different sizes. In react native. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 ageNameParagraph: {
        marginTop: 20, // Added marginTop here for spacing between picture and name/age
        marginBottom: 20, // More spacing
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.surface, // Apply a subtle background
        padding: 10, // Padding for better touch targets
      },

              <View style={styles.ageNameParagraph}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" size={30} style={styles.icon} />
                <Text style={{alpha: 0.87, fontFamilyfamily: 'regular', fontSize: 30, lineHeight: 30}}>{editableUserInfo.name},</Text>
                <Text style={{alpha: 0.87, fontFamilyfamily: 'regular', fontSize: 18, lineHeight:20}}> {editableUserInfo.age}</Text>
              </View>
```

Comment: Try adding `display: flex;` to your ageNameParagraph CSS class

Comment: didn't help....

Comment: Move your `<MaterialCommunityIcons>` component out of your `<View>`. That way only your `Text` components get the `ageNameParagraph` styles applied.

Comment: Can you should what do you want to have and what you have now?

Answer (score 0):

To display the name and age on the same line with different sizes in React Native, you can adjust the styles of your `Text` components. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
<MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" size={30} style={styles.icon} />
<View style={styles.ageNameParagraph}>
  <Text style={{ alpha: 0.87, fontFamily: 'regular', fontSize: 30, lineHeight: 30 }}>
    {editableUserInfo.name},
  </Text>
  <Text style={{ alpha: 0.87, fontFamily: 'regular', fontSize: 18, lineHeight: 20 }}>
    {editableUserInfo.age}
  </Text>
</View>
```

The `fontSize` and `lineHeight` properties have been set differently for the name and age to achieve the desired size difference.

Make sure to replace `fontFamilyfamily` with `fontFamily` for the correct property name. Also, ensure that your font styles are correctly applied.